# Can't make valid responsive website because positioning

Tags: html, css, debugging, responsive-design, position

I try to make a responsive website but I tend to believe because I'm using positiong + right and left it makes me some serious problems. I need to do that without grid. 
That's what happens when I make the window a little bit smaller, some of it go left: https://i.imagesup.co/images2/cdf13e4d1939b4041c55ab3b59799762e3d8f32d.png.

And when it gets to the media query it's definitely not responsive. Every change in the window size under 786px seem differently.
https://i.imagesup.co/images2/007f47c1df59bdf745a531d55c9c8965270508aa.png

Only the what inside the first white box + what's inside + what above is really responsive.

CSS

```
body {
    margin: auto 0;
    direction: rtl;
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
}

.img-center {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;

}


#img-below {
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 8%; 
    width: 8%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 80px;
}

h1 {
    color:#0099ff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    bottom:  120px;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 157px;
    font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;

}

.icons {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: #0099ff 5px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 100%;;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

#DivIcons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 170px;
}

p {
    font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;

}

article {
    width: 160px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 455px;
    right: 397px;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;
}

.square {
    border:5px solid #0099ff;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-radius: 30%;

}

.circle {
    border:5px solid #0099ff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.Pservice {
    color: #0099ff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
}

#service {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
position: relative;
bottom: 1710px;
right: 440px;
}

#position3 {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 70px;
    right: 157px;
}

#form {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1830px;
    right: 593px;
}

input {
    border-radius: 6px;
}

input:nth-child(1)
{
width: 250px;
height: 20px;
margin-left: 10px;
}
input:nth-child(2)
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 20px;
}

#textarea {
    width: 520px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#submit {
    background-color: #0099ff;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 120px;
    position: relative;
    right: 200px;
    bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#FirstWhite{
    width: 750px;
    height: 320px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 460px;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#AboutWhite {
    width: 180px;
    height: 650px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1113px;
    right: 385px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#ServiceWhite {
    width: 555px;
    height: 165px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1855px;
    right: 580px;
}

#FooterWhite {
    width: 555px;
    height: 463px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 2292px;
    right: 580px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px)
{
    #img-main {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 150px;
    }

    #img-below {
        width: 30vw;
        height: 30vh;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    h1, h2 {
        font-size: 7vw;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;
    }

    #flex-mobile1 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        position: relative;
        top: 70px;
        right: 120px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    #flex-mobile2 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        position: relative;
        top: 150px;
        left: 133px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }


    #FirstWhite{
        width: 100vw;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: white;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 490px;
        z-index: -1;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    #AboutWhite {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: white;
        position: relative;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 588px;

     }

     article {
         position: relative;
         right: 0px;
         width: 85vw;
         margin-right: 10px;
         height: 100px;


     }
     #ServiceWhite
     {
         position: relative;
         bottom: 650px;
         right: 0px;
         width: 100vw;

     }

     #service
     {
         position: relative;
         bottom: 500px;
         right: -120px;

     }

     #FooterWhite
     {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 1080px;
        right: 0px;
        width: 100vw;
     }

     #form {
         position: relative;
         right: 0px;
         bottom: 620px;
         margin-right: 15px;
     }

     #inside-form {
         position: relative;
         right: 40px;
     }
}
```

[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/firefun365/pen/YzKorQZ)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code helps you to build on top it. As of now the media query is set for 600px, you may change it to your desired break point.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}
header {
  position: relative;
}
.header-img {
  width: 100%;
}
.rounded-img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  bottom: -60px;
}
.rounded-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
h1,
h2 {
  font-family: "M PLUS Rounded 1c", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.titles {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
h1 {
  color: #0099ff;
  font-size: 5rem;
  padding: 60px 20px 0 20px;
}
h2 {
  color: #808080;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}
.icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.icons a {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 15px;
  border: 5px solid #0099ff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.icons a img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.content-section {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.article-right,
.article-left {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "M PLUS Rounded 1c", sans-serif;
}
.article-right {
  order: 2;
  width: 180px;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.article-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.article-left div {
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.article-left .shapes-section {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.article-left .form-section {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .icons {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .icons a {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .content-section {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .article-right,
  .article-left,
  .article-left .shapes-section,
  .article-left .form-section {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .article-left {
    order: 2;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .article-right {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <img class="header-img" src="https://www.westsidemovement.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Lets-Go-Scripture-800x200.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="rounded-img">
      <img src="https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/960x0/https%3A%2F%2Fblogs-images.forbes.com%2Frainerzitelmann%2Ffiles%2F2019%2F06%2FE0MG76-e1560965378507-1200x1270.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="titles">
      <h1>אלברט איינשטיין</h1>
      <h2>פיזיקאי תיאורטי</h2>
      <div class="icons">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-logos-6/512/10-waze-512.png" alt="" />
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://thebrightwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/facebook-icon-blue.png" alt="" />
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-thin-line-color/21/20-512.png" alt="" />
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://www.trzcacak.rs/myfile/full/311-3111799_social-media-computer-icons-logo-blue-area-png.png" alt="" />
        </a>

        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/452/whatsapp.png" alt="" />
        </a>

        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/thin-line-color-1/21/13-512.png" alt="" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="content-section">
      <article class="article-right">
        your right content
      </article>
      <article class="article-left">
       <div class="shapes-section">
         shapes content here
        </div>
        <div class="form-section">
          form here
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
  </main>
</div>
```